# Problem with Python requests on my server

Tags: python, django, python-requests

On my server side this happens:

Example link `r = requests.get("http://www.instagram.com/{invalid username}/`

Checking the r.ok gives the result `True` and r.status_code gives `200`

Example link2 `r = requests.get("http://www.instagram.com/{valid username}/`

Now I'm confused, as the same thing yields different result on my local machine. The invalid one returns a `404` and the valid one returns a `200`.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What behavior do you expect?

Comment: I get status code 200 even when it's supposed to be a 404.

Comment: Could you show your `{invalid username}` which you try? or just check yourself this url in a browser?